# Make a system app Android

Tags: java, android

I'm coding an Android Application to activate the Warranty of my Company's Phone automatically

- Bootupreceiver : Call Khoidong.java Service when Phone Boot Up
- Khoidong.java service: Send data (Imei, Model) to my Server

Everything works ok. (User App)
I want to make it to system app for factory reset it still there

I sent my APK to the manufacturer and asked they to add my apt to system/app

They sent my a firmware that included my apt in system app. But it don't work.

I try to copy my apk myself to system/app. it works fine when I restart. But when I factory reset the phone, the phone boots up, my app force closes.

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

System apps are baked into the ROM image, and signed with the same key the ROM was signed with, giving them extra access to the system.

You cannot add a new system app on the same level without updating the ROM image of the device, and even then you'll need the OEM key to sign your app and you will have to request them to include it in their ROM.

Having a rooted device allows standard apps to gain extra access without being system apps.

Comment: I'm already have a rooted phone. Just copy it to system/app it work ok. But when Factory reset it force close. when i press OK my services restart and send data to my server

Comment: When you Factory reset, the app exists,but when you try to open it, it force closes. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Not try to open. Because it automatic start by Bootup Receiver. After factory reset and boot. My phone say my app force Close

Comment: Before rebooting or resetting,copy the required libs from `/data/data/<appname>/lib` to `/system/lib` as well.

Comment: Yes, I already read that. But when I'm going to /data/data/<appname>/. There are no lib folder, just cache folder and a lib file without any extension. No folder, no .so file

Comment: I don't think there is any solution to the after-reset problem you are facing.